# Navigation back to the Salesforce Mobile App after Navigating Away

Tags: lightningnavigation, salesforce-mobile-app, deep-linking

I am attempting to integrate a Vue app into a business process that starts with Salesforce Mobile app.  The Vue app needs to access the camera on the mobile device and, as a result, must be hosted externally and can not run in something like a Lightning:container element.  The Vue app lives in an AWS S3 bucket for now with Cloudfront providing https with a generic certificate.

The current process is this:

1. From the Mobile app, the user initiates a quick action (object-based) that invokes a lightning component.  The lightning component uses lightning:navigation to navigate the user to the Vue app.  This seems to work just fine.
2. The user scans a QR code using the device camera.  The Vue app returns the content of the QR code with is a URL and querystring containing a record Id and a string.  This seems to work just fine.
3. (this is where things don't work so I'll just describe what I'd like to have happen here)  In an ideal world, as soon as the scanning app picks up the QR code data successfully I'd like to navigate the user back to the Salesforce mobile app along with the QR code data.  What does currently work is that an anchor tag with a query string/URI can invoke an Apex class when clicked that performs the necessary data update using URL Schemes (used to be called a deep link).  The data is updated in Salesforce.  What doesn't work is any attempt I've made to navigate the user back to the Salesforce mobile app.

I had hoped to just close the Vue app which should take the user back to the last screen they were on in the Mobile app.  This does not seem to be possible since the Vue app can't "self-close" due to limitations in modern browsers.  I also attempted to use a second deep link to take the user to the record page where the initial action was invoked.  That didn't seem to work either.

I was trying to figure out if Lightning nav service could somehow hold on to the tab it opens (if it returned a promise, for instance) and then close the tab once data was received back but it doesn't look like that is part of the implementation in the nav service.

I'm not sure if code would be helpful here, but I can post it if requested.  I'm really just looking for advice on a general approach as to how to close out my Vue app and get back to the Mobile app.  If anyone has faced something similar I'd love to understand your approach.  Any strings to pull on would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.